# Control On updation from UI or apex

Tags: apex, community, user

can we Have acess or control in salesforce to control whether a particular updation should be From UI only or It should be through apex/process builder(backend)?
 I have One Field stage on an opportunity that should be updated to particular value only by apex/Processbuilder/workflow, but this should not be updated by UI. How to achieve this?

Comment: Your question isn't perfectly clear. Are you asking if you can somehow create a field that can be updated via the UI, but **not** Apex? Or, are you asking if there's a way you can create a field that can **not** be updated in the UI, but can be updated via Apex? Can you please [edit] your question to clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I want to restrict update only from UI

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a field as "read only" on the user profile. This will restrict access to the field in the UI and API, but will still allow Workflow and Apex to update the values on the backend.

Comment: yes but twist is that I have field stage and restriction should be for particular 2 values say A and B in stage i.e. out of 7 values.As U say if field is read only it will restrict for all values.